# How to cross join the the left side table to the right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to cross join the data with one column with distinct name with all other rows data , as in the image:
Left side with main table Value  Right side is the result i need.
already tried with *`cross join`* but in this case it is not working properly, we have at one scenario with more than 1.5 million records.

Bene column(B1,B2) will main  column , and corresponding A1 with 5 values, against B1, so, 5*5 25 rows should be insert to another table for B1.
(how much alert are there corresponding (B1,B2), and that must be repeated in the resulted column)

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also are you really using *both* 2008 and 2012? Both are completely unsupported (the former for almost 4 years). As you are using *both* should we assume that any solution can't use 2012+ features?

Comment: Is that two tables, or one table and the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh with one tables only the Fisrt row B1 and B2 considered.

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not understood globally, and only used where you live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it was not clear in your description, it appears from the way you highlighted your expected results that you wish to cross join all ALERT values with all CUSTOMER/TXN pairs for each BENE.

This can be done by first splitting out the values into two views (eliminating possible duplicates) and then joining them back together based on the common BENE values.

The query below uses Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to extract two views or slices of your original data and join them back together to achieve the desired results.

```
;WITH Alerts AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT BENE, ALERT
    FROM DATA
    WHERE ALERT IS NOT NULL
), Customers AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT BENE, CUSTOMER, TXN
    FROM DATA
    WHERE (CUSTOMER IS NOT NULL OR TXN IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT COALESCE(A.BENE, C.BENE) AS BENE, A.ALERT, C.CUSTOMER, C.TXN
FROM Alerts A
FULL OUTER JOIN Customers C
    ON C.BENE = A.BENE
ORDER BY BENE, ALERT, CUSTOMER, TXN
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Vwxg9bt) for a demo with some extra test data.

Comment: instead of FULL OUTER JOIN , Can we Use INNER JOIN, because BENE is common in both tables.

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks for the feedback. For the supplied example, that is true, but other data may differ. This data appears to be two data sources zipped up in a single table (an apparent bad design). I'm assuming that the number of distinct elements from one source might not be the same as the other, and I extend that allow for potentially zero elements from one source or the other. Both the DISTINCT and the FULL OUTER JOIN might be overkill, but I included both for increased safety.

Comment: ok, thanks , i got the exact reason

Answer (score 3):

It's too bad you don't write what actually was wrong with cross join, it should work.

```sql
with cte as (
    select *
    from 
(
    values 
        ('B1', 'A1', 'C1','T1')
    ,   ('B1', 'A2', 'C2','T2')
    ,   ('B1', 'A3', 'C3','T3')
    ,   ('B1', 'A4', 'C4','T4')
    ,   ('B1', 'A5', 'C5','T5')
    ,   ('B2', 'A1', 'C1','T1')
    ,   ('B2', 'A2', 'C2','T2')
    ,   ('B2', 'A3', 'C3','T3')
    ,   ('B2', 'A4', 'C4','T4')
    ,   ('B2', 'A5', 'C5','T5')
    ) x (Bene, alert, customer,txn)
)
select c2.bene, c2.alert, c2.customer, c2.txn
FROM    cte x
inner join cte c2
    ON  c2.bene = x.bene
order by c2.bene, c2.alert, c2.customer, c2.txn
```

Something like this perhaps? Basically you join the table with itself and generate the needed rows.

Answer (score 0):

cross join should work.  It seemed to work when I tried it.

```
declare @tmpData as TABLE (
    BENE VARCHAR(10),
    ALERT VARCHAR(10),
    CUSTOMER VARCHAR(10),
    TXN VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT @tmpData
VALUES
    ('B1', 'A1', 'C1', 'T1'),
    ('B1', 'A2', 'C2', 'T2'),
    ('B1', 'A3', 'C3', 'T3'),
    ('B1', 'A4', 'C4', 'T4'),
    ('B1', 'A5', 'C5', 'T5'),
    ('B2', 'A1', 'C1', 'T1'),
    ('B2', 'A2', 'C5', 'T5'),
    ('B2', 'A3', 'C6', 'T6'),
    ('B2', 'A4', 'C7', 'T7'),
    ('B2', 'A5', 'C8', 'T8'),
    ('B3', 'A6', 'C8', 'T8'), -- Two alerts, one customer
    ('B3', 'A7', null, null),
    ('B4', 'A6', 'C1', 'T1'), -- Two alerts, three customers
    ('B4', 'A7', 'C2', 'T2'),
    ('B4', null, 'C3', 'T3'),
    ('B5', 'A1', 'C1', 'T1'), -- Two each, but with duplicates
    ('B5', 'A1', 'C2', 'T2'),
    ('B5', 'A2', 'C2', 'T2');

    with cte 
    as
    (
    select BENE,ALERT from @tmpData
    )
    select cte.BENE,cte.ALERT,tmp.CUSTOMER, tmp.TXN from cte 
    cross join  @tmpData tmp 
    where tmp.BENE=cte.BENE 
    and cte.BENE='B1'
    order by cte.BENE, cte.ALERT
```

output

```
BENE    ALERT   CUSTOMER    TXN
B1  A1  C1  T1
B1  A1  C2  T2
B1  A1  C3  T3
B1  A1  C4  T4
B1  A1  C5  T5
B1  A2  C1  T1
B1  A2  C2  T2
B1  A2  C3  T3
B1  A2  C4  T4
B1  A2  C5  T5
B1  A3  C1  T1
B1  A3  C2  T2
B1  A3  C3  T3
B1  A3  C4  T4
B1  A3  C5  T5
B1  A4  C1  T1
B1  A4  C2  T2
B1  A4  C3  T3
B1  A4  C4  T4
B1  A4  C5  T5
B1  A5  C1  T1
B1  A5  C2  T2
B1  A5  C3  T3
B1  A5  C4  T4
B1  A5  C5  T5
```